# Structure Node.js (Express) app

Tags: node.js, express

How should I structure Node.js (Express) app? I do so:

- app.js - starting the server
- router.js - routing requests and starting functions from other files.
- pages.js - render not-static pages. Example: request to database and render result
- control.js - operation with alteration. Example: creation/updating line in database.
- db.js - connection to database and creation model for ORM.

What should be changed? How to do better?

(Sorry for bad english)

Comment: Why do you think something needs to be changed?

Comment: This question is OT for SO not because it's a dumb question, but because it's both too broad, and opinion-based. I'd probably start by looking for Express tutorials and example projects.

Comment: every question can still be answered with a helpful answer instead of just a dumb vote down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you heard about **[Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/)**? It is a webapp generator, which is a very useful tool to automatically build webapp skeletons.

There are a lot of different generators of any web technology/framework you wish to use. Maybe a good idea can be having a look and exploring how these generators structure the code for you, which could give you an idea in how to keep your code organized.

You can [Search for generators](http://yeoman.io/generators/) at **Yeoman**'s site, just type `Express` and try different ones.